# string pattern and regex

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I have a file with different lines, among which I have some lines like

```
173.194.034.006.00080-138.096.201.072.49934
```

the pattern is 3 numbers and then a dot and then 3 numbers and then a dot, etc.

I want to use awk, grep, or sed for this purpose. How do I express this regular expression?

Comment: What exactly do you need to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get lines with 1 series like 123. exists, do

```
 grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.' file > numbersFile
```

If you want 2 series like 123.345., then do

```
 grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.' file > numbersFile
```

etc, etc.

Each `[0-9]` means match only one occurance of characters in the range between 0-9 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

Because the '.' char has a special meaning in a normal grep regexp, you nave to escape it like `\.` to indicate "Just match the '.' char (only!) ;-)

There are fancy extensions to grep that allow you to specify the pattern once, and include a qualifier like `{3}` or sometimes `\{3\}` (to indicate 3 repetitions). But this extension isn't portable to older Unix like Solaris, AIX, and others.

Here's a simple test to see if your system supports qualifiers. (Super Grep-heads are welcome to correct my terminology :-).

```
   echo "173.194.034.006.00080-138.096.201.072.49934" | grep '[0-9]\{10\}\.'
   echo "173.194.034.006.00080-138.096.201.072.49934" | grep '[0-9]\{2\}\.'
```

The first test should fail, the 2nd will succeed if your grep supports qualifiers.

It doesn't hurt to learn the long-hand solution (as above), and you can be sure this will work with any grep.

IHTH.

Comment: I want to know more about like \{3\} , should it be like '[0-9]\{3\}\.'?

Comment: note that Ed Morton's posix char classes should work in a sed that supports `\{3\}`, i.e. instead of `[0-9]\{3\}\.`, try `[[:digit:]]\{3\}\.' Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

In awk I'd probably build up the string and then search for it as:

```
BEGIN {
   p  = "[.]"
   d  = "[[:digit:]]"
   d3 = d d d                     # or d"{3}"
   d5 = d d d d d                 # or d"{5}"
   re = d3 p d3 p d3 p d3 p d5    # or "(" d3 p "){4}" d5
}
$0 ~ re "-" re
```

but it really all depends what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it, these are IP addresses, followed by a port number, a dash and then the IP address/port number combination again.

If you're on a modern UNIX/Linux system then

```
grep -P '(\d{3}\.){4}\d{5}-(\d{3}\.){4}\d{5})'
```

would do the trick -- although may not be the most portable way to do it. This uses the '-P' for "use Perl regular expressions" option, which some people might consider to be cheating!

You didn't say if you've got extra text either before or after these strings on the line. If you have then you can use the '-o' option just to extract the matched text and ignore everything else.